# Split using regex creates 2 empty elements in array

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, split

I need to split a string into 2 pieces using regex, so I used the following code:

```
var str = "This is a test";
var list = str.split(/(test)/);
```

**Required output:**

```
list = ["This is a ", "test"]
```

Instead of 2 this gives me 3 elements in the array (last one is empty). I understand that regex finds nothing after the 2nd match so it adds an empty (3rd) element. Is there any way that I can modify my code so I get exactly 2 elements thus avoiding the last empty element?

Note: the above code is a simplified version for which we can use other options besides regex but I would have to use regex.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem here... What do you actually want to get? Maybe `str.match` would be better.

Comment: Edited the post with the required output

Comment: If you are looking for regex what will handle that, then the answer is - no, you can't - it is not a matter of regex, but `split()` method itself

Comment: What if you had "hello test world", or `"test was there"`? `"This is a test".split(/(?=test)/)` works in your case, but will fail in the others.

Comment: @Jerry `.match` is not splitting the original string. Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @AzizShaikh The regex with `.match` is different... `str.match(/(.*?)(test)$/).slice(1);`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the approaches mentioned by Kobi and Jerry. May have to fine tune a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "This is a test";

var list = str.split(/(test)/,2);
```

list:  `["This is a ", "test"]`

Comment: or you can define the split function for u to prevent this case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps overkill if you can guarantee that you are only expecting an array of length two but given the nature of the question a more robust solution may be to use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove all empty strings from the array - including entries in the middle of the array which would arise from several delimiters appearing next to each other in your input string.

```
var list = str.split(/(test)/).filter(
    function(v){ return v!=null && v!='' }
);
```

Comment: Assumes modern browsers (or `IE9+`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with checking if last element is empty or not:

```
var last = list.pop();
    last.length || list.push(last);
```

or:

```
list[list.length-1].length || list.pop();
```

or even shorter:

```
list.slice(-1)[0].length || list.pop();
```

To handle first empty element (`test was there` as @Kobi suggested) use:

```
list[0].length || list.shift();
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, nor do I have an exact idea why, but the first piece of code doesn't seem to work (or I'm not using it correctly, since I'm not that used to JS), though the others are, but that's not a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

This is giving me the results you want:

```
var str = "This is a test";
var list = str.split(/(?=test)/g);
```

`(?=` is a lookahead, it doesn't capture the word `test` so that stays in the array after splitting.